# PyQt5: Can't reload previously used QWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I'm currently programming some sort of bar tab-keeping thing for the student dorm I'm currently working at.
For that I have two different a QScrollAreas with two QWidgets with one QGridLayout each. One for the User selection and the other for the selection of the item to purchase.

Everything works fine when I switch to the item selection interface with
`self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.itemWidget)`, however I also implemented a back button in case the wrong user was selected, which should go back to the first QWidget initiated: `self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.userWidget)`, which in my mind should just load up the previously built Layout again, but instead i get this error:

`RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QWidget has been deleted`

Where did I go wrong? Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What about a web-based solution, e.g. https://github.com/FREILab/unary?

Comment: @ypnos what's the point of suggesting a completely different framework?

Comment: From my experience with this stuff, I don't think using Qt is very practical for this application. However I also answered the question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however I don't have a lot of time left and therefore don't have time to learn a new framework either :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `setWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#setWidget) clearly states:

> The widget becomes a child of the scroll area, and will be destroyed when the scroll area is deleted or when a new widget is set.

What you need to do is call `takeWidget()` first before setting another widget.

Alternatively, you could use a `QStackedWidget` as container for the two widgets.

Comment: Ok thank you. How exactly do i use takeWidget()? And what do I replace with QStackedWidget? Do I put QStackedWidget as the central widget of the QScrollArea and then switch between the other two widgets I already have?

Comment: Hey! Nevermind I figured it out! I just reassign the self.itemWidget by calling takeWidget() on the scrollArea.

Could you still let me know on how to use the QStackedWidget with a QScrollArea for future reference? When I attach a QStackedWidget to the QScrollArea and then the pre-existing Widget to my QStackedWidget it doesn't show anything anymore...

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what goes wrong with your stacked widget in scroll area but there is other people reporting issues with the combination on SO. Maybe you just stick to the scroll area as you have it.

Comment: Okk! Thanks again!